# Can not connect to multiple SignalR Instance with IIS server

Tags: iis, websocket, signalr

I have written an application using **SignalR** library, this Application works fine with IIS Express but if I deploy this Application on IIS Express than only one web client can get updated,
if more than one tab is open then none of them will get updated,

if I debug the web page I get the error as:

```
Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': null
```

Comment: This is an old issue caused by the default AMI setting. You must assign a hostname in the host file. Many people just use terraform / cloudformation to change the value before the system startup. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-user

Comment: This is intended design of sudo, which use gethostbyname. It depends either on local hostname inside /etc/localhost or your VPC DNS broadcast. So to solve this problem for good, always add your host name inside /etc/localhost. Don't bet on the luck of DNS resolution.